# why smplayer don't show subtitle?

Tags: ubuntu, video, linux-mint, media-player

When I try to load the subtitle or drag and drop the subtitle on the movie, it does not show any reaction and the subtitle is not displayed. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Breaking your question into another question rather than trying to tack it on to your old one. (+1)  I will look at this later and see if I might be able to help.  I am on a Windows box right now.. I will be at my Linux workstation later.